# how to reverse a char array in c?

Tags: c

i am trying to print a reversed char but the c program displays some junk and i can't figure out why...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
void isPoli(char *str);

int main()
{
    char name[30] = "abcde";
    isPoli(name);

    return 0;
}

void isPoli(char *str){
    char reversed[strlen(str)+1];
    for(int i = 0; i<=strlen(str);i++){
        reversed[i] = str[strlen(str)-i-1];
    }
    printf("\n%s - %s\n", reversed,str);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your array indexes are off.  When i = strlen(str) your code will look like this:

```
reversed[strlen(str)] = str[-1];
```

str[-1] is undefined.  You also do not NULL terminate reserved.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is in how you are indexing the array. The below code reflects the needed changes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
void isPoli(char *str);

int main()
{
    char name[30] = "abcde";
    isPoli(name);

    return 0;
}

void isPoli(char *str){
   int iLen = strlen(str) - 1;
   char reversed[iLen];
   for(int i = 0; i<= iLen ;i++){
       reversed[i] = str[ iLen - i  ];
   }
   reversed[iLen + 1] = (char)0x0;
   printf("\n%s - %s\n", reversed,str);
}
```

Comment: I think being a little more specific about exactly what is wrong with "the indexing" would greately help OP and others with similar issues